# Best way to achieve desired class hierarchy behaviour

Tags: python, class, oop

Let's say I'm trying to create a package for the users to make new classes of cars. Originally I have a simple code structure:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, diesel_engine):
        self._engine = diesel_engine

    def _start(self):
        pass

# Then the user can do
class Truck(Car):
    pass
```

But now I want to enhance the functionality and cater to both conventional car and electric car in the package. The problem is that the constructor of the base class `Car`  would now need to accept either `diesel_engine` or `electric_motor`; and also, the class method `_start` would perform different things accordingly (so for example, it will call `_ignite` or `_close_circuit`).
Am I better off adding the derived classes in my package:

```
class Conventional(Car):
    def _start(self):
        pass

class ElectricVehicle(Car):
    def _start(self):
        pass
```

or is there a better way by using, e.g., decorator? Essentially I want the end-user to make new derived classes by passing in appropriate arguments and deriving from a single base class (because all other class methods are identical except for `_start`)

Answer (score 2):

The abstract `Car` should accept an abstract `Engine`.

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, engine: Engine):
        self._engine = engine

    def start(self):
        self._engine.start()
```

In the real world, engines can be treated as black boxes with some inputs (gas/electricity) and some outputs (axle rotation, exhaust). `Engine`s do their best to hide things a `Car` does not need to deal with whenever possible. The following interface provides a way to start the engine and control its speed:

```
class Engine:
    def start(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def set_speed(self, speed):
        raise NotImplementedError


class DieselEngine(Engine):
    def start(self):
        self._ignite()

    def set_speed(self, speed):
        self._set_gas_rate(speed / KILOMETERS_PER_LITER)
```

At some point, though, it becomes better to *compose* and use data to make decisions rather than an inheritance hierarchy. Unless the hierarchy is strictly disjoint with no overlaps across multiple traits, I would avoid inheritance and use other ways to emulate "polymorphic behavior".

For instance, if `Car` needs to pipe the engine's exhaust to the outside air, it's a bit silly to define another subclass of `Engine` called `ExhaustEngine`. At this point, interfaces (`HasExhaust`), [PODs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c), dictionaries, and so on might be easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

The derived classes should set the engine type.  The generic car doesn't know that.  Same with, for example, number of wheels.

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self):
        self.engine = 'unknown'

class Truck(Car):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.engine = 'diesel'

class ElectricCar(Car):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.engine = 'electric'
```